# How to use maven settings from external settings.xml for maven-android-plugin project?

Tags: android, maven-3

I created an Android Maven project just as described in this post ([link to post](http://stand.spree.de/wiki_details_maven_archetypes)). I use the last archetype: android-release.

So everything is working fine, except when I want to release a version, I can not figure out how to pass the certificate properties. I created an settings.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>android-debug</id>
        <properties>
            <sign.keystore>/Users/me/.android/debug.keystore</sign.keystore>
            <sign.alias>androiddebugkey</sign.alias>
            <sign.storepass>android</sign.storepass>
            <sign.keypass>android</sign.keypass>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>android-release</id>
        <properties>
            <sign.keystore>/Users/me/myKeystore.keystore</sign.keystore>
            <sign.alias>myAlias</sign.alias>
            <sign.storepass><![CDATA[myPassword]]></sign.storepass>
            <sign.keypass><![CDATA[myPassword]]></sign.keypass>
        </properties>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

Then I run:

```
mvn -s setttings.xml clean release:prepare release:perform -Pandroid-release
```

But I keeps ignoring the values defined in the android-release profile.

Any ideas how to get this working? When I just run:

```
mvn -s setttings.xml clean install -Pandroid-release,release
```

it builds an apk and signes it with the right certificate. So maybe it's just the maven-enforcer-plugin, which is not able to read the properties from the settings.xml?

Answer (score 2):

> mvn -s setttings.xml clean release:prepare release:perform -Pandroid-release

I don't know the answer why it keeps ignoring the values defined in the android-release profile.

However, if you use maven-release-plugin, the normal way we used to achieve what you want is add the following settings to the profile which you want to trigger at release phase:

```
<profile>
    <id>android-release</id>
    <properties>
        <sign.keystore>/Users/me/myKeystore.keystore</sign.keystore>
        <sign.alias>myAlias</sign.alias>
        <sign.storepass><![CDATA[myPassword]]></sign.storepass>
        <sign.keypass><![CDATA[myPassword]]></sign.keypass>
    </properties>
    <!-- via this activation the profile is automatically used when the release 
        is done with the maven release plugin -->
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>performRelease</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

So now if you do `mvn -s setttings.xml clean release:prepare release:perform`, maven-release-plugin will automatically pick up `profile android-release`.

Note that the profile is automatically activated at release phase, if there is no maven-release-plugin involved, you can still use the classic way `mvn -s setttings.xml clean install -Pandroid-release` to make build process use the specific `profile android-release`.

Check out [maven-release-plugin doc](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#useReleaseProfile) for more details.